# Can I see custom flags, or is this a comment automatically added?

Tags: support, flagging, 10k-tools

Looking at the list of the flagged posts, I noticed the following one:

[image: screenshot]

There is not a flag reason for an answer that is duplicating another answer already given for another question. I guess that two are the possibilities:

- I am seeing what added as custom reason from who flagged the answer.
- The system automatically added that comment.

In the first case, I would not see which specific flagging reason should have been selected from the flagger; in the latter case, I would be surprised if the software looks for duplicated answers posted on different questions, and automatically flags them.

Are then trusted users able to see some of the flags that use a custom reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would be surprised if the software looks for duplicated answers posted on different questions, and automatically flags them.

This is what happens.